# Python: Read datatype LineString from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I am trying to read the LineString datatype into python from a CSV file. Could someone help me parse it efficiently. This is what I have so far. I am trying to avoid using geopandas for now as my Anaconda install is borked.

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
road_data = pd.DataFrame(["LINESTRING (-79.38247448302049 43.64530088371729, -79.382245982944 43.64525978372071, -79.3816974827792 43.64537518376642)"], columns=['geometry']))
road_data.geometry = road_data.geometry.astype(LineString)
road = road_data.iloc[0]
print(road['geometry'].length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shapely.wkt.loads`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.wkt.loads) to load a string into a shapely object:

```
import shapely.wkt
road_data.geometry = road_data.geometry.apply(shapely.wkt.loads)
```

Output:

```
>>> road_data
                                            geometry
0  LINESTRING (-79.38247448302049 43.645300883717...
```

Now, it may appear as though nothing happened. But if you take a look at the actual value, you can see it's a `shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString` object:

```
>>> road_data.geometry[0]
<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x12772eb50>

>>> road_data.loc[0, 'geometry'].length
0.0007926752962040786
```